# JavaScript: does this prevent the object being able to garbage collected?

Tags: javascript

I have a `map` and an object `obj`.

```js
const map = {}

let obj = {descritpion: 'foo'}
```

and I use `map` to `obj.descritpion` as one of its key

```js
map[obj.descritpion] = 'bar'
```

my question is, does this or will `map` prevent `obj` from being able to be garbage collected by the browser? for example, if I set `obj` to `null` as in

```js
let obj = null
```

will the object `{descritpion: 'foo'}` get garbage collected by the browser?

Comment: are you trying to redeclare obj?

Comment: Yes, that object is gone. `obj.description` is not a reference to any object, it's just a string.

Comment: Does this help?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#garbage_collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value `{descritpion: 'foo'}`, of type `"object"`, is being referenced by the variable `obj` first:

```js
let obj = {descritpion: 'foo'}
```

Then, you access `obj.descritpion` in the line:

```js
map[obj.descritpion]
```

You are actually accessing the prop `descritpion` of the reference `obj`, not doing a reference to **obj** itself. Which is the string `'foo'`.

When you do:

```js
// let obj = null // note: actually using 'let' again would fail because it has been already declared in the scope
obj = null
```

Then, the value object: `{descritpion: 'foo'}` is no longer referenced by any other object, therefore it's garbarge collected.

And at this point, if you run again `map[obj.descritpion]`, you will get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'descritpion' of null
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, setting `obj` to `null` will remove the only reference to `{descritpion: 'foo'}`, making it eligible for garbage collection.

Executing this statement:

```js
map[obj.descritpion] = 'bar'
```

simply reads `obj.descritpion`, which is a string.  `map` contains no reference to `obj` in this case.